# how to update mono version from Visual Studio 2019 for mac

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, mono, visual-studio-mac

I was trying to use a different version of mono (5.16.0) (default is 6.6.0) for my xamarin forms project but I was not able to select a particular version in visual studio under 
Visual Studio -> Preferences -> Projects-> .Net Runtimes but I was not able to find the .NET Runtime options in that section from which I could have changed the mono version for the project.

[Visual Studio version 8.2.2 having .Net runtimes option under Projects Section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIm7d.png)

[Visual Studio version 8.4.8 does not have the .Net Runtime option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0ogI.png)

I have tried deleting the existing mono framework(6.6.0) and installing the required framework(5.16.0) but then I was not able to open visual studio , a pop up appeared stating This version of visual studio requires Mono framework (6.0.14xx or higher) to open.

provide a solution which take cares of both these situations.

Answer (score 4):

The .NET Runtimes section is considered an advanced feature and in more recent Visual Studio for Mac versions it was disabled by default.

It can be enabled in two ways:

- **Setting an environment variable using Terminal**

Open a Terminal window and run:

```
launchctl setenv MD_FEATURES_ENABLED RUNTIME_SELECTOR
```

Then run Visual Studio for Mac. Does not have to be run from the Terminal window.

- **Enable the feature using the Feature Switch extension**

Install the [Feature Switch extension](https://addins.monodevelop.com/Project/Index/401) from the Extension Manager, which is available from the main menu when you select Extensions. Select the Gallery tab and search for it. Restart Visual Studio for Mac after installing the extension.

From the main menu select Preferences - Environment - Feature Switch.

Then check/tick RUNTIME_SELECTOR.

Then restart Visual Studio for Mac so the feature is enabled.